# Aforge Video-Picture quality

Tags: aforge

Even though webcam quality is 5mp , webcam seems and takes low quality of picture.

Is there any way to fix this and raise quality to maximum possible?

Comment: You need to add code so we can analyze what is the problem..

Comment: sorry for making you busy for this. I found out that desiredframesize function solves the problem. thank you.